# Unpublished node

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

List with Views published nodes in the form of a table. Add to a table with a column that will contain a link. By clicking on the link ajax request should be sent, which makes the node unpublished.

I have views, have a link, have alert-ajax. But I don't understand how I can change the status from 0 to 1 programmatically.

My code in controller -

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\RemoveCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class CustomAjaxLinkController extends ControllerBase{

  public function customAjaxLinkAlert($node) {

    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    $node = $query->execute();
    $status =  $node-> isPublished();
    if ($status === TRUE) {
      $node->status = 0;
        $node->save();
    }

    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    $selector = '.customAjaxLinkAlert' ;
    $response->addCommand(new RemoveCommand($selector, $node));
    return $response;
  }
}      
                                                                                                                                    There is an error in it, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong
```

Comment: Could you please sketch the problem a bit more clearly.
From this only, it is difficult to see the exact issue and help you with it.

Comment: im edit my qestion

Answer (score 1):

You can past data's via ajax in a Drupal Controller

```
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/your_module/your_function',
            data: {'data': data},
          });
```

Then in your Controller

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\your_contoller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Class your_contoller.
 */
class your_contoller extends ControllerBase {

  public function your_function() {
    do what you want
  }

}
```

OR

Your button is inside a form and will submit the value.

Comment: thanks, but I need something different. Maybe your solution will help someone else

Comment: Please explain in what way different? Sharklalu's answer seems ok.